# SumConverge does not give a valid result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I wanted to see if the function SumConverge worked for the following summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n^p}$$
We can clearly see that for $p>1$ the series converges and for $p\le1$ diverges by the comparison test. I tried:

```
SumConvergence[(Sin[n])^2/n^4, n]
```

However, I do not get an evaluation. Why so?
$$$$I also tried $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n^p}\right|$$
Whose convergence or divergence can by found by Dirichlet's Test. However mathematica seems to not understand such input. I tried:

```
SumConvergence[Abs[(Sin[n])/n], n]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give `SumConvergence` a little help:

```
SumConvergence[TrigReduce[Sin[n]^2/n^2], n]

True
```

Answer (score 2):

**previous post (may or may not be correct implementation)**

```
SumConvergence[(Sin[n])^2/n^p, p] (* this gives condition for convergence *)
(* Abs[n] > 1 *)

SumConvergence[(Sin[Abs@n > 1])^2/n^2, n]
(*True*)

SumConvergence[(Sin[Abs@n > 1])^2/(n^-1), n]
(*False*)
```

**new post**

```
SumConvergence[(Sin[n])^2/n^p, p] (* this gives condition for convergence *)
(* Abs[n] > 1 *)
```

I think you should just use `Sum` and put `VerifyConvergence -> True`. I just read in the documentation that `Sum` automatically calls `SumConvergence`.

```
Sum[(Sin[n])^2/(n^4), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}, VerifyConvergence -> True]

(* 1/180 (\[Pi]^4 - 45 PolyLog[4, E^(-2 I)] - 45 PolyLog[4, E^(2 I)]) *)

Sum[(Sin[n])^2/(n^-1), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}, VerifyConvergence -> True]
(* Sum::div: Sum does not converge. >> *)
```

Comment: Limit test does not prove if a sum is convergent. I want to use SumConvergence for p=4

Comment: @user372003 does this suffice `Sum[Sin[n]^2/n^4, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]`. the output is `1/180 (\[Pi]^4 - 45 PolyLog[4, E^(-2 I)] - 45 PolyLog[4, E^(2 I)])`

Comment: I specifically stated that I would prefer the use of SumConvergence instead of Sum. Although, I appreciate you trying to help. So the convergence of such sequence cannot be evaluated with SumConvergence? Also, if you try Sum[Sin[n]^2/n,{n,1,\[Infinity]}] you don't get an an evaluation, why?

Comment: @user372003 can you check my answer again. if it makes sense now

Comment: Looks good for p>1 but does not work for p=1. Can you explain why you put Abs@n>1? Thank you!

Comment: @user372003 actually my previous implementation may or may not have been correct. Therefore I have updated my answer. I recommend to use `Sum` In case when `Sum` returns "does not converge" then its obvious that convergence condition failed. If it returns a value then it has converged to the returned value.